# Makefile command substitution

Tags: make, command-substitution, gnu-make

My Makefile:

```
all: ...(other rules) clean

clean:
    rm $(find . -type f -executable)
```

When I delete `clean` rule from the above Makefile everything works as expected. After adding, `make` (also `make clean`) command results in:

```
rm 
rm: missing operand
Try 'rm --help' for more information.
make: *** [Makefile:46: clean] Error 1
```

What causes problem here and how can I solve?

Comment: Is there a reason not to use `find . -type f -executable -delete`? Also note that `$` introduces the expansion of a makefile variable.

Comment: @Kusalananda actually I'm not aware of `-delete` opt in `find`. Do you say that `$` has a special meaning in `Makefile` and there is no workaround for this?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

There are several issues.

##### Passing a $ sign in a Makefile to the shell

You want to run the command

```
rm $(find . -type f -executable)
```

to let the shell do the command substitution. To do this you need to write

```
clean:
        rm $$(find . -type f -executable)
```

with the dollar doubled as Make itself uses `$`.

##### Handing the case where there is nothing to "clean"

If the output of `find` is empty, then after command substitution

```
rm $(find . -type f -executable)
```

becomes

```
rm
```

and the typical `rm` command complains that you haven't told it what to remove. One way to address this is to use `xargs` to process the output of `find`. It takes the output of `find` and if there is any it splits it into blocks and runs rm.

```
clean:
        find . -type f -executable | xargs rm
```

##### Handling arbitrary characters in filenames

Unix filenames are made up of components separated by `/` characters. The components themselves can be any sequence of characters except `/` and NUL. In particular a component can include newline characters, spaces, tabs, `*`.

For the command substitution case (`rm $(find . -type f -executable)`) case the shell will process the output of find. So white-space characters will cause word splitting, `*` characters will  cause filename "globbing" to take place etc. For reasonable implementations of `xargs` this is avoided.

If filenames begin with `-` then `rm` might consider them to be options to the command. The simple way to avoid this is to add `--` to the command to indicate "end of options".

The major remaining issue is newlines. `xargs` splits the input on newlines, so if you have a file called `abc\ndef` then `find` will output

```
abc
def
```

and `xargs` will invoke `rm` with 2 filenames`abc` and `def`.

To work around this, tell both `find` and `xargs` to use the 1 character (NUL) that can't appear in filenames as the deliminator rather than newline.

```
clean:
        find . -type f -executable -print0 | xargs -0 rm --
```

#### Best solution, if your `find` supports it

```
clean:
        find . -type f -executable -delete
```

Here you have find directly removing the files, if any. It is more efficient as it doesn't need to start additional processes. There are no shells or xargs processes to need to escape characters. No special characters to tell `make` to process. Handles the "no files to delete" case correctly.